# embedded youtube videos not playing in WKWebView while exact same videos work in UIWebView

Tags: ios, youtube, wkwebview

When I load a web page into a UIWebView (even a www.youtube.com page) that contains an embedded youtube video, it plays just fine for IOS7 or IOS8. But when I switch to WKWebView (IOS8) and load the same web page, the youtube video doesn't play at all on the first click, then plays for a second or two on subsequent play clicks (on the youtube player). Like it is running out of buffer space and pausing until I hit play again only to play for another second.

From Safari this (or any other) youtube video plays from start to finish on the same LAN. Likewise, as I mentioned earlier, UIWebView has no problem inside of IOS7 or IOS8. So it is not a problem with my wireless data thru put or connection.

Is there something I need to do to keep the player going? Maybe increase the streaming video buffer space for WKWebViews?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured out why this is happening and also why no one else was affected by it. WKWebView and indeed IOS 8 handles several things that are not deprecated yet act differently in IOS 8. And this is one.

My app samples audio from the microphone in real time. This was fine in prior versions of IOS, but apparently in IOS 8 when a WKWebView starts a video stream, the audio sample can kill it (god only knows precisely why).

However, I need to be able to sample audio with WKWebView but I don't necessarily need to do it when a video is playing. So the challenge will be to figure out when the user has clicked on a youtube or vimeo or apparently any other streaming video and pause my audio sampler while the video is streaming. At the moment I don't know how to do that.

I also discovered another difference between IOS8 and prior when using UIView animations. prior to IOS 8 you could animate a swap between images in the UIWebView and the animation was persistent only as long as you set the duration AND you didn't have to enable animations.

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade1" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Now in IOS8, apparently you have to set a listener and disable animations after it finishes, otherwise your UIView animation is applied to all sorts of unexpected, and even native, behaviors. Like finger scrolling a native list or when the user vertically scrolls a web page in the UIWebView. Disable the animations and these strange affects on other objects disappear.

```
   [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
```

And now I am totally confused about what the commit does. It doesn't seem to be needed in IOS 8 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To know when the video is playing, you can try [this solution from Paulo Fierro](https://paulofierro.com/blog/2015/10/12/listening-for-video-playback-within-a-wkwebview).